# Strategy for locale sensitive sort with pagination

Tags: java, postgresql, sorting, pagination, locale

I work on an application that is deployed on the web. Part of the app is search functions where the result is presented in a sorted list. The application targets users in several countries using different locales (= sorting rules). I need to find a solution for sorting correctly for all users.

I currently sort with ORDER BY in my SQL query, so the sorting is done according to the locale (or LC_LOCATE) set for the database. These rules are incorrect for those users with a locale different than the one set for the database.

Also, to further complicate the issue, I use pagination in the application, so when I query the database I ask for rows 1 - 15, 16 - 30, etc. depending on the page I need. However, since the sorting is wrong, each page contains entries that are incorrectly sorted. In a worst case scenario, the entire result set for a given page could be out of order, depending on the locale/sorting rules of the current user.

If I were to sort in (server side) code, I need to retrieve all rows from the database and then sort. This results in a tremendous performance hit given the amount of data. Thus I would like to avoid this.

Does anyone have a strategy (or even technical solution) for attacking this problem that will result in correctly sorted lists without having to take the performance hit of loading all data?

Tech details: The database is PostgreSQL 8.3, the application an EJB3 app using EJB QL for data query, running on JBoss 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

Are you willing to develop a small Postgres custom function module in C? (Probably only a few days for an experienced C coder.)

`strxfrm()` is the function that transforms the language-dependent text string based on the current LC_COLLATE setting (more or less the current language) into a transformed string that results in proper collation order in that language if sorted as a binary byte sequence (e.g. `strcmp()`).

If you implement this for Postgres, say it takes a string and a collation order, then you will be able to order by strxfrm(textfield, collation_order). I think you can then even create multiple functional indexes on your text column (say one per language) using that function to store the results of the strxfrm() so that the optimizer will use the index.

Alternatively, you could join the Postgres developers in implementing this in mainstream Postgres. Here are the wiki pages about this issues: [Collation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:Collate), [ICU](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:ICU) (which is also used by Java as far as I know).

---

Alternatively, as a less sophisticated solution if data input is only through Java, you could compute these strxfrm() values in Java (Java will probably have a different name for this concept) when you add the data to the database, and then let Postgres index and order by these precomputed values.

Answer (score 0):

How tied are you to PostgreSQL? The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/locale.html) isn't promising:

> The nature of some locale categories is that their value has to be fixed for the lifetime of a database cluster. That is, once initdb has run, you cannot change them anymore. `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` are those categories. They affect the sort order of indexes, so they must be kept fixed, or indexes on text columns will become corrupt. PostgreSQL enforces this by recording the values of `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` that are seen by initdb. The server automatically adopts those two values when it is started.

(Collation rules define how text is sorted.)

Google throws up [patch under discussion](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:Collate):

> PostgreSQL currently only supports one collation at a time, as fixed by the LC_COLLATE variable at the time the database cluster is initialised.

I'm not sure I'd want to manage this outside the database, though I'd be interested in reading about how it can be done. (Anyone wanting a good technical overview of the issues should check out [Sorting Your Linguistic Data inside the Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/globalization/pdf/TWP_AppDev_Linguistic_Sorting_10gR2.pdf) on the [Oracle globalization site](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/globalization/index.html).)

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4 (the current version) supports locale settings per database. It's far from perfect, but it's a lot better than 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to switch the database `order by` order. Therefore, one has to consider other solutions.

If the number of results is really big (hundred thousands ?), I have no solutions, except showing only the number of results, and asking the user to make a more precise request. Otherwise, the server-side could do, depending on the precise conditions....

Especially, using a cache could improve things tremendously. The first request to the database (unlimited) would not be so much slower than for a query limited in number of results. And the subsequent requests would be much faster. Often, paging and re-sorting makes for several requests, so the cache would work well (even with a few minutes duration).

I use EhCache as a technical solution.
Sorting and paging go together, sorting then paging. 
The raw results could be memorized in the cache.

To reduce the performance hit, some hints:

- you can run the query once for **result set size**, and warn the user if there are too many results (ask either for confirming a slow query, or add some selection fields)
- **only request the columns you need**, let go all other columns (usually some data is not shown immediately for all results, but displayed on mouse move for example ; this data can be requested lazyly, only as needed, therefore reducing the columns requested for all results)
- if you have **computed values**, cache the smaller between the database columns and the computed values
- if you have **repeated values** in multiple results, you can request that data/columns separately (so you retrieve from the database once, and cache them only once), retrieve only a key (typically, and id) in the main request.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout this packge: http://www.fi.muni.cz/~adelton/l10n/postgresql-nls-string/. It hasn't been updated in a long time, and may not work anymore, but it seems like a reasonable startingpoint if you want to build a  function that can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This module is broken for Postgres 8.4.3. I fixed it - you can download fixed version from http://www.itreport.eu/__cw_files/.01/.17/.ee7844ba6716aa36b19abbd582a31701/nls_string.c and you'll have to compile and install it by hands (as described at related README and INSTALL from original module) but anyway sorting is working incorrectly. I tried it on FreeBSD 8.0, LC_COLLATE is cs_CZ.UTF-8

Comment: Actually it looks like UTF-8 + Postgres + Collation is the most bad combination that ever exists. Most probably we have to apply some ICU patch to Postgres itself, because simple test showed that strcoll works incorrectly for cs_CZ.UTF-8 under FreeBSD.

Comment: Solution is found - for FreeBSD have to mark use ICU (I select version 4) - at this case Postgres will use internal collation instead of FreeBSD broken one. nls_string for this case is obsolete. Plus, of course, set correct LC_COLLATE for DB.